# Как сделать так, чтобы сообщения из ВКонтакте приходили на мой сайт с помощью VK API?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Суть в том, чтобы все сообщения, которые приходят, скажем, в чей-то аккаунт в ВК, пришли на мой сайт когда этот пользователь введет свои данные ВК на моем сайте. И чтобы он смог ответить на них. Можете пример кода API скинуть? Можно не ВК (другие социальные сети), главное увидеть как это реализуется. До этого не работала с API.

Буду признательна за любую помощь, ссылки, учебные пособия и т.д.

Comment: Юный кулл хацкер детектед!

Comment: 1) https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll 2) https://vk.com/dev/messages

Comment: А че "люди", а не "пипл"?

Comment: @u_mulder не знаю, ну если вы хотите....

Answer (score 1):

В общем, всё не так просто, но можно. В документации ВК написано:

1) https://vk.com/dev/messages

Методы для работы с личными сообщениями.
Для моментального получения входящих сообщений используйте LongPoll сервер.
Обратите внимание: доступ к работе с методами секции с ключом пользователя ограничен

2) Соответственно, то, как всё это реализовать написано тут: https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll

Comment: Уаау, спасибо большое!!

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать, но придется запариться с интерфейсом)
Как уже написали, нужно использовать User Longpoll с токеном, у которого есть доступ к секции сообщений(например при создании токена использовать id офф. мобильного приложения вк, или kate mobile).

Но есть одна большая проблема с получением токена пользователя, есть 2 варианта:

1. Пользователь вводит лог/пасс от своего аккаунта, и вы его
   авторизуете(при этом записывая токен в БД)
2. Можно дать пользователю ссылку и инструкцию, по типу: перейди по этой ссылке, и скопируй токен/всю ссылку после авторизации и отправь ее на сайт в какое-то поле.

Теперь, имея токен пользователя, есть 2 варианта реализации доставки событий.

1. Сложный вариант - Используя вебсокеты(хотя можно и ajax), подключаем пользователя к серверу, и он будет ждать событий(новых сообщений). Т.к. одновременно может быть много пользователей, то необходимо будет как-то запустить N скриптов с user LP, и подключить NoSQL базу данных. Когда приходит событие, то его нужно отправить в базу. Таким образом, мы будем хранить очередь событий для каждого юзера отдельно. А в server вебсокет скрипте, нужно будет поставить таймер, например на каждую секунду, чтобы он выгружал и удалял выгруженные события из nosql, и отправлял соответствующее событие соответственному пользователю. А на фронте эти события ловить и отображать.
2. Простой вариант - реализовать user LP на js и запускать его у клиента. Тут не потребуется никакой обработки, все работает у клиента. Пришло событие - отобразить.

Соответственно, нужно сделать поле ввода(и возможно загрузки медиафайлов), чтобы юзер мог отвечать. Тут все просто, если обработка на сервере, то по вебсокету отправляете запрос на отправку и отправляете сообщение(при этом, опять же, добавляя событие в nosql как исходящщее). А если делать в браузере, то после отправки событие само придет, как исходное.

Библиотеки для вебсокетов на PHP:
https://github.com/walkor/Workerman,
https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io

Библиотека для VK API на PHP с удобной реализацией user Longpoll:
https://github.com/digitalstars/simplevk
Пример кода:

```php
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use DigitalStar\vk_api\vk_api;
use DigitalStar\vk_api\LongPoll;
$vk = vk_api::create('login', 'password', VERSION);//или используйте токен вместо лог/пас
$vk = new LongPoll($vk);
$vk->listen(function()use($vk){ //longpoll для пользователя
    $vk->on('message_new', function($data)use($vk) { //обработка входящих сообщений
        $vk->initVars($id, $message);
        $vk->reply($message);
    });
});
```

В одном ответе все подводные камни описать сложно, у нас есть [беседа](https://vk.me/join/AJQ1dzQRUQxtfd7zSm4STOmt) в ВК для помощи по vk api, в которой можно быстро получить ответ на вопрос.